# Search & update within a BSON array using C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am on the way to learn MongoDB. What I'm trying to do is search a BSON array for a BSON document by _id. Here is my code so far-

```
 var courses = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Course");
 var query = new QueryDocument("_id", courseId);

 BsonDocument course = courses.FindOne(query);
 var exists = course.Contains("Lessons");
 if (exists)
 {
       BsonArray lessons = course["Lessons"] as BsonArray;
 }
```

I would like to search within the **lessons** array for an specific BSON document and update that document.

Any help?

Comment: Why do you work with BsonDocument instead of using classes, which would be much easier?

Answer (score 0):

Can you define a c# class to model the documents stored in the `Course` collection? If so, then it will be much easier to work with the data and you can use simple LINQ queries to work with your data.

[Mongo c# driver - BsonDocument Object Model vs. Your Own Domain Classes](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/#bsondocument-object-model-vs-your-own-domain-classes)

You could model the Course document as follows.

```
 public class Course
        {
            public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

            public IEnumerable<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
        }

public class Lesson
        {
            public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

You would need to define a another c# entity to represent what is contained in the `Lesson` sub-document.
But once you have that complete, then you can just write Linq queries to search for the data you are looking for

```
    var collection = database.GetCollection<Course>("Course");
    var course = collection.AsQueryable().First(c => c.Id == id);

    var mathLesson = course.Lessons.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == "Math");
    if (mathLesson != null)
    {
        mathLesson.Name = "AdvancedMath";
    }

    collection.Save(course);
```